# ToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) - casting back to a DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview, casting, contextmenustrip, sender

I have a **WINFORM** app with a **DataGridView** control , hooked into a **ContextMenuStrip** control.
The **ContextMenuStrip** fires events to essentially perform copy / paste between the **DataGridView** and the **Clipboard**.

```
private void copyToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  CopyClipboard();
}

private void CopyClipboard()
{
  DataObject d = myGrid.GetClipboardContent();
  Clipboard.SetDataObject(d);
}

private void pasteCtrlVToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  PasteClipboard();
}
```

I've added another **DataGridView** to my application and wish to share **ContextMenuStrip** between them since, per my code above, it's hardcoded to my grid, **myGrid**.

I believed it would simply be an easy exercise to modify my code to cast a new **DataGridView** control from the **sender**:

```
private void copyToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  CopyClipboard(sender);
}

private void CopyClipboard(object sender)
{
  var grid = (DataGridView)sender;
  DataObject d = grid.GetClipboardContent();
  Clipboard.SetDataObject(d);
}

private void pasteCtrlVToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 var grid = (DataGridView)sender;
  PasteClipboard(grid);
}
```

but of course, I found that the **sender** was instead the **ToolStripMenuItem**.

Is there a way to reference the original **DataViewGrid** via the **sender**, or **EventArgs e** ?

And, thank you for reading :)

Answer (score 2):

Ahh, think I got it!

```
private void copyToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  CopyClipboard(sender);
}

private void CopyClipboard(object sender)
{
  var grid = (DataGridView)sender;
  DataObject d = grid.GetClipboardContent();
  Clipboard.SetDataObject(d);
}

private void pasteCtrlVToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var item = (ToolStripMenuItem)sender;

  ToolStripMenuItem t = (ToolStripMenuItem)sender;
  ContextMenuStrip s = (ContextMenuStrip)t.Owner;

  var grid = (DataGridView)s.SourceControl;

  // Pulling the backend datatable just to enhance the example.
  // Going Live, the consumer of the "grid" will do the extraction.
  BindingSource bs = (BindingSource)grid.DataSource;
  DataTable dt = (DataTable)bs.DataSource;


  PasteClipboard(grid, dt);
}
```

I found the solution here: http://discuss.joelonsoftware.com/default.asp?dotnet.12.474610.5

Finally per this thread, I wanted to add **ToolStripMenuItem** as a thread **tag** but i don't have the rep.
Appreciate someone with the rep adding it to the **tag** cache so that I can update this tread;
hopefully making somone else's life, with same issue, a lil' easier finding this thread! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var grid = CType(sender, DataGridView)
```

or

```
var grid = CType(sender.parent, DataGridView)
```

Comment: PaShKa, Thank you for your reply but CType(sender, DataGridView) is the vb version of c# (DataGridView)sender and sender doesn't have a property called parent :(

Comment: Can you convert Sender to ToolStripMenuItem? I think it has .parent available

Comment: You can't convert a ToolStripMenuItem to a DataGridView.  The sender, in this case, is a ToolStripMenuItem.

Comment: This might be the solution... tried to post it as an answer but, too much the noob to do it.  Anyway, not sure it's completely what I'm looking for but, it's a start: http://discuss.joelonsoftware.com/default.asp?dotnet.12.474610.5